# Error displaying current date

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to display the current date, but after running this code, it force closes the application. I tried this example to display the day, month and year in a `TextView`:

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the error is that it's looking for `com.example.test.MainActivity`, whereas your activity is `com.example.test.ListingActivity1`. Either fix your deployment, or change the class name.

(Note that this has nothing to do with what the activity *does* - it hasn't got that far.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your activity name in your manifeast file

```
            <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.ListActivity1"  <-----
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't mentioned the name of the activity properly in the Android Manifest file , Check your manifest file for the Class name .

Comment: thanks it work i change the name of the activity in mainfest  to ListActivity1

Answer (score 0):

Everything your code is ok accept you miss to declare your activity name in your meanifeast.xml file. Please check it.

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.ListActivity1"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest file

```
<activity android:name="com.example.test.ListActivity1"
              android:label="ListActivity">
    </activity>
```